# Magento 2 How to create options array for use in backend grid

Tags: magento2, extensions, collection, grid

all. Fairly new in Magento development. I am trying to get a dropdown select element in UI grid with values read from database working.

Currently I have it working in a non-preferred manner with the use of ObjectManager, but I gather it's not the 'proper' way.

What I currently use is:

```
<?php
namespace WDT\Faq\Model\Category\Source;

class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    //*
    // @var \WDT\Faq\Model\Category
    //
    protected $_category;

    //*
    // Constructor
    //
    // @param \WDT\Faq\Model\Category $category
    //
    public function __construct(
        \WDT\Faq\Model\Category $category
    )
    {
        $this->_category = $category;
    }

    /**
    * Get options
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options[] = ['label' => '', 'value' => ''];
        //
        //  Q-n-D solution
        //
        $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $connection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection')->getConnection('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION');
        $result1 = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM wdt_faq_category");

        foreach ($result1 as $n => $row) {
            $options[] = [
                'label' => $row['name'] . ' ' . __('Category'),
                'value' => $row['category_id'],
            ];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

So after many tries with extending ResourceModel and/or Block instances I'am stumped. What is the right way to implement this, and get the intended result?

Comment: do you have a collection resource model or a repository for your `\WDT\Faq\Model\Category` class?

Comment: umm. Yes, Marius. All of the above. I just didn't know I could get away with so little.. See comment @Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the bare minimum requirements using dependency injection. Utilizing the ObjectManager directly should be avoided at all costs.

Source Model:

```
<?php
namespace WDT\Faq\Model\Category\Source;

class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface {
    /**
     * @var \WDT\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var array|null
     */
    protected $_options;

    /**
     * @param \WDT\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \WDT\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray() {
        if ($this->_options === null) {
            $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create();

            $this->_options = [['label' => '', 'value' => '']];

            foreach ($collection as $category) {
                $this->_options[] = [
                    'label' => __('%1 Category', $category->getName()),
                    'value' => $category->getId()
                ];
            }
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

Category Collection:

```
<?php
namespace WDT\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Category;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('WDT\Faq\Model\Category', 'WDT\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Category');
    }
}
```

Category Resource:

```
<?php
namespace WDT\Faq\Model\ResourceModel;

class Category extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('wdt_faq_category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Category Model:

```
<?php
namespace WDT\Faq\Model;

class Category extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('WDT\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Category');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks Andrew, I was sure it'd be something simple ( well, in a way ;) ) but I kept needlessly injecting and/or inserting all sorts of non-needed extras. But this works like a charm.